# SQL Server: Include Missing data in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server that looks as follows,

Table 1:

```
Store   Type
100      A
101      B
102      B
103      B
104      C
105      C
106      A
107      A
108      D
109      D
110      C
111      B
112      D
```

and table 2:

```
Store   Units
100       5
101       3
102      10
103       6
104       6
105       8
```

I want to combine the two tables in a query with a relationship link between the Store column of the two tables. The problem i have is that if i create a query between the two then the stores from 106 to 112 does not appear in the table. The query looks as follows,

```
SELECT dbo.Table1.Store, 
       dbo.Table1.Type, 
       dbo.Table2.Units 
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
  ON dbo.Table1.Store=dbo.Table2.Store
```

What should i do to include the stores that does not appear in Table2 (106-112) but in Table1 and make there Units = 0, such that the query table look as follows,

```
Store   Type    Units
100       A       5
101       B       3
102       B      10
103       B       6
104       C       6
105       C       8
106       A       0
107       A       0
108       D       0
109       D       0
110       C       0
111       B       0
112       D       0
```

Comment: Read this article before you write any more SQL - http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1):

You want a left outer join instead of an inner join:

```
SELECT t1.Store, t1.Type, COALESCE(t1.Units, 0) as Units
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.Store = t2.Store;
```

I also introduced table aliases for your query to make it more readable.  Note the use of `coalesce()` so you get `0` for `Units` instead of `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dbo.Table1.Store, dbo.Table1.Type, coalesce(dbo.Table2.Units, 0) As Units
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON dbo.Table1.Store=dbo.Table2.Store
```

Comment: please add some explanatory notes to your answer, showing how it solves the problem, and where the OP was going wrong.